# Imported Azure SQL Database always sizes at 250GB

Tags: azure-sql-database

I have the issue that setting up a new SQL DB bacpac import (S3 Standard) always has a max size of 250 GB - just as if the parameter 'DatabaseMaxSizeBytes' gets omitted. Here the code:

```
$sdvobjDbImport = New-AzureRmSqlDatabaseImport `
                    -ResourceGroupName $sdvstrSqlsResourceGroupName `
                    -ServerName $sdvstrSqlsName `
                    -AdministratorLogin $sdvstrAdminLI `
                    -AdministratorLoginPassword $sdvsstrAdminPW `
                    -DatabaseName $sdvstrDatabaseName `
                    -Edition $sdvstrDbEditionAtImport `
                    -ServiceObjectiveName $sdvstrServiceObjectiveAtImport `
                    -DatabaseMaxSizeBytes 262144000 `
                    -StorageKey $sdvstrStorageKey `
                    -StorageKeyType 'StorageAccessKey' `
                    -StorageUri $sdvstrStorageUri `
                    -EA Stop
```

It should be 250 MB, but not GB. I don't need such a monster; scaling down afterwards (from 250 GB to 250 MB) gives problems with long operations times on the DB. Any idea what is wrong in my code? Google does not give an answer, either.

Comment: Hi, If my answer is helpful for you,  please  accept(mark) it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested and have the same problem: the parameter `-DatabaseMaxSizeBytes` doesn't works. No matter which value we use, it will all create the database with the max storage 250G (DTU Standard S2).

The Azure Document use `-DatabaseMaxSizeBytes 5000000`, I tested and it also doesn't works.

**Solution**:

After the import completed, We must set the database size manually, here's the sample command:

```
Set-AzSqlDatabase -DatabaseName "TestDB" -ServerName "sqlservername" -ResourceGroupName "resourcegroup" -MaxSizeBytes "104857600"
```

> **Note**:
>
> The value of `-MaxSizeBytes` must be: 100M, 500m, 1GB, 2GB, 5GB, 10GB, 20GB, 30GB, 40GB, 50GB,100GB, 150GB, 200GB, 250GB.

You also can test

You can get this value from Portal:

[image]

I use the [new Azure PowerShell Az module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/new-azureps-module-az?view=azps-3.0.0).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for confirming my observation. Like you I also reduce the size then when down scaling the database after the bacpac import.

Answer (score 0):

Az is replacing AzureRM so this bug probably won't be fixed. The solution is using New-AzSqlDatabaseImport instead of New-AzureRmSqlDatabaseImport.

Here is an example of how to use it.

```
$importRequest = New-AzSqlDatabaseImport 
   -ResourceGroupName "<your_resource_group>" `
   -ServerName "<your_server>" `
   -DatabaseName "<your_database>" `
   -DatabaseMaxSizeBytes "<database_size_in_bytes>" `
   -StorageKeyType "StorageAccessKey" `
   -StorageKey $(Get-AzStorageAccountKey -ResourceGroupName "<your_resource_group>" -StorageAccountName "<your_storage_account").Value[0] `
   -StorageUri "https://myStorageAccount.blob.core.windows.net/importsample/sample.bacpac" `
   -Edition "Standard" `
   -ServiceObjectiveName "P6" `
   -AdministratorLogin "<your_server_admin_account_user_id>" `
   -AdministratorLoginPassword $(ConvertTo-SecureString -String "<your_server_admin_account_password>" -AsPlainText -Force)
```

As you can see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-import#import-into-a-single-database-from-a-bacpac-file-using-powershell) they are favoring the use of New-AzSqlDatabaseImport.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution but your internet copy-paste code is useless as an answer, as well as your link to SQL Server Powershell. Also, ever heard of the "magic number" 1,024 when it is about converting units of data?

Comment: Seen. The problem of that guy is different from my. But again, thanks for the reference!