# Powershell script increasing Azure SQL Database storage size with 10%

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell

I need to create powershell script that will increase Azure SQL database storage space with 10%.
With GB its not a problem, but I don't have an idea how to do it with %. 
I have something like that:

```
$1 = Get-AzSqlDatabase -ResourceGroupName "testRG" -ServerName "test-sql" -DatabaseName "test-sqldb"
$2 = $1.MaxSizeBytes
```

But how to point that MAxSizeBytes will be 100% and add 10% more ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use [Set-AzSqlDatabase](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.sql/set-azsqldatabase?view=azps-4.2.0) and set the parameter `-MaxSizeBytes` to the desired value.

Should be something like:

```
$db = Get-AzSqlDatabase -ResourceGroupName "testRG" -ServerName "test-sql" -DatabaseName "test-sqldb" 

Set-AzSqlDatabase -ResourceGroupName "testRG" -ServerName "test-sql" -DatabaseName "test-sqldb" -MaxSizeBytes $($db.MaxSizeBytes*1.1)
```

You probably have to check the valid sizes in Azure Portal.
According to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58712699/imported-azure-sql-database-always-sizes-at-250gb) the values are limited to specific sizes.

Comment: Check size, check if actually found actual database, etc. 